# get specific lines from a repeated range pattern in a text file

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, pattern-matching

Wow, this sounds so complicated in the title, but I assume it is not quite so.

I have text files that have basically this layout:

```
Stimulus ...
...
...
...
Response
Stimulus ...
...
...
...
Response
```

I used sed to get everything in between and then further extracted information I needed.

```
sed -n -e '/Stimulus/,/Response/ p'
```

However, sometimes the participants do not respond, in which case the file looks like this:

```
Stimulus ...
...
...
...
Stimulus ...
...
...
...
Response
```

In this special case, my script will not get what I am looking for. So, I am looking for a way to extract the information if and only if the pattern1 is followed by pattern2, not pattern1 again.

Let me know, if I formulated it unclear. I am more then happy to provide further information.

Comment: does `'/Stimulus/,/Response|Stimulus/` work? Hm.. probably not. This is usually solved with an awk script that sets a flg for both values, when both are true, do what you need to. Good luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One dirty way, although it seemed to work in my test, could be to reverse the file content, search from `Response` to `Stimulus` and reverse again the result.

Assuming following input data:

```
Stimulus 1...
...
...
...
Stimulus 2...
...
...
...
Response 2
Stimulus 3...
...
...
...
Response 3
Stimulus 4...
...
...
...
Stimulus 5...
```

The command:

```
tac infile | sed -ne '/Response/,/Stimulus/ p' | tac -
```

Yields:

```
Stimulus 2...
...
...
...
Response 2
Stimulus 3...
...
...
...
Response 3
```

---

**EDIT**: For an example with isolated `Response` parts. There is to filter twice (based on a comment of the OP):

```
tac infile | 
  sed -ne '/Response/,/Stimulus/ p' | 
  tac - | 
  sed -ne '/Stimulus/,/Response/ p'
```

Comment: Elegant. Will test it an be back.

Comment: I tested it and there was a small problem as there are not only isolated Stimulus parts, but also Isolated response parts. However, doing the procedure twice does the trick: tac infile | sed -ne '/Response/,/Stimulus/ p' | tac - | sed -ne '/Stimulus/,/Response/ p' ;)

Comment: thus making it tic-tac-toe!

Answer (score 5):

This is a pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) solution:

```
tmp=()
while read l; do
  [[ $l =~ ^Stimulus ]] && tmp=("$l") && continue
  [ ${#tmp[@]} -eq 0 ] && continue
  tmp+=("$l")
  [[ $l =~ ^Response ]] && printf "%s\n" "${tmp[@]}" && tmp=()
done <infile
```

It starts to fill up the array `tmp` if a list starting with `Stimulus` found. If another `Stimulus` arrives, it just clears `tmp` and starts the job again. If `Response` found, it prints the content of the `tmp` array. Actually `printf` built-in does an implicit loop.

Input:

```
cat >infile <<XXX
...
Response 0
...
Stimulus 1
...
Stimulus 2
...
Response 2
...
Stimulus 3
...
Response 3
...
Response 4
XXX
```

Output:

```
Stimulus 2
...
Response 2
Stimulus 3
...
Response 3
```

Comment: Will output stuff on each `Response`, even if there's no `Stimulus` before. Also, the regex is overkill: `[[ $l = Response* ]]` would've been enough.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Could you tell me what will be the output if there is no line starting with `Stimulus` I guess an empty line. :) Of course, You can use the glob matching. I prefer [tag:regex].

Comment: You're outputing the `tmp` array on each `Response`, whatever happens, even if there weren't any `Stimulus` before. In this respect, you're not quite answering the OP. Please see the OP's comment in @Birei's answer.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: You are right. This is solution for the original question. I corrected, thx!

Comment: We now pretty much have the same algorithm. `+1`. `:)`.

Answer (score 4):

Other option is switch to `perl` and its flip-flop (range operator):

```
perl -lne '
    BEGIN {
        ## Create regular expression to match the initial and final words.
        ($from_re, $to_re) = map { qr/\A$_/ } qw|Stimulus Response|;
    }
    ## Range, similar to "sed".
    if ( $r = ( m/$from_re/o ... m/$to_re/o ) ) {
        ## If inside the range and found the initial word again, remove 
        ## all lines saved.
        if ( $r > 1 && m/$from_re/o ) {
            @data = ();
        }
        ## Save line.
        push @data, $_;
        ## At the end of the range, print all lines saved.
        if ( $r =~ m/E0\z/ ) {
            printf qq|%s\n|, join qq|\n|, @data;
            @data = ();
        }
    }
' infile
```

Assuming an input file as:

```
Stimulus 1...
...
...
...
Stimulus 2...
...
...
...
Response 2
Stimulus 3...
...
...
...
Response 3
Stimulus 4...
...
...
...
Stimulus 5...
```

It yields:

```
Stimulus 2...
...
...
...
Response 2
Stimulus 3...
...
...
...
Response 3
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) solution that tries to minimize stupid side effects:

```
#!/bin/bash

out=()

while read -r l; do
   case "$l" in
       Stimulus*) out=( "$l" ) ;;
       Response*) ((${#out[@]}!=0)) && { printf "%s\n" "${out[@]}" "$l"; out=(); } ;;
       *) ((${#out[@]}!=0)) && out+=( "$l" ) ;;
   esac
done < infile
```

It also handles the case where there's a `Response` but no `Stimulus`.

Answer (score 4):

***Updated to handle isolated Responses***

```
awk '
/Response/ { 
    if (p==1) {
        for(;k<length(a);) {
            print a[++k]
        }
        print $0
    }
    delete a;k=p=0
} 
/Stimulus/ {
    if (p==1) {
        delete a; i=0
    }
    p=1
} 
p { a[++i]=$0 }' log
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Really nice & easy job for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), one-way, no unwanted pipes & tools:

```
sed -n 'H;/^Stimulus/{h;d};/^Response/{x;s/^Response//;tk;p;:k;d}' file
```

---

Input File:

```
Stimulus 1...
bad
bad
bad
Stimulus 2...
...
...
...
Response 2
Stimulus 3...
...
...
...
Response 3
Stimulus 4...
bad
bad
bad
bad
Stimulus 5...
...
...
...
...
Response 5
bad
bad
bad
bad
Response 6
bad
bad
bad
```

---

And output:

```
$sed -n 'H;/^Stimulus/{h;d};/^Response/{x;s/^Response//;tk;p;:k;d}' file
Stimulus 2...
...
...
...
Response 2
Stimulus 3...
...
...
...
Response 3
Stimulus 5...
...
...
...
...
Response 5
```

---

And my code for GNU [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '{a[++i]=$0};/^Response/ && a[1] !~ /^Response/ {for (k=1; k<=i; k++) {print a[k]}};/^Stimulus|^Response/ { delete a; i=0; a[++i]=$0}' file
```

As you can see, I need too much awk code ...